# Is there a way to convert my old data macros from table to vba after a database split?

Tags: vba, ms-access, ms-access-data-macro

I recently split my ms access database into a front, and back end. I didn't know that the data macros that were on the table wouldn't be able to work anymore. I was wondering if there is any way to convert these to vba.

```
if IsNull([prmQuoteID])
    RaiseError
        Error Number 10
        Error Description Please specify quote details.
end if
RunDataMacro
    Macro Name Quotes.GetNextQuoteNumber
SetLocalVar
    Name varNextQuoteNumber
    Expression = [ReturnVars]![retNextQuoteNumber]
RunDataMacro
    Macro Name Quotes.UpdateQuoteTotal 
    parameters
        prmQuoteId = [prmQuoteId]
if [varNextQuoteNumber]=0
    RaiseError
        Error Number 20
        Error Description Unable to retrieve next quote number!
stopmacro
end if
Look Up A Record In SELECT Quotes.ID, Quotes.StatusID, Quotes.QuoteNumber, Quotes.Submitted FROM Quotes; 
    Where Condition  = [ID]=[prmQuoteID]
    if [StatusID]>=10
        RaiseError
            Error 30
            Error Description Quote has already been marked submitted.
    End If
    Edit Record
        SetField
            Name StatusId
            Value = 10
        SetField
            Name QuoteNumber
            Value = [varNextQuoteNumber]
        SetField
            Name Submitted
            Value = Date()
```

Example of Data Macro
[Data Macro Photo of above code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8f9AL.png)

It connects to an form on click embedded macro in the front end database
[On click embedded macro](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Mg4Dw.png)

```
OnError
    go to Macro Name
    ErrorHandler
SetTempVar
    Name YesNoMessage
    Expression = "Quote cannot be changed once it is submitted."
SetTempVar
    Name YesNoMessage2
    Expression = ""Do you want to continue?""
OpenForm
    Form Name YesNoAlert
    View Form
    Window Mode Dialog
If [TempVars]![YesNoResponse]=False
    stopmacro
End If
RunMenuCommand
    command saveRecord
RunDataMacro
    Macro Name Quotes.Submit
    Parameters
        prmQuoteId = [txtID]
RefreshRecord
RunMacro
    Macro Name SetFromState
SetTempVar
    Name AlertMessage
    Expression "Quote #" & [txtQuoteNumber] & " is now submitted for approval."
OpenForm
    Form Name Okalert
    View Form
    Window Mode Dialog
Submacro: ErrorHandler
    RunMacro
        Macro Name Utilities.ErrorAlert
End Submacro
```

I was wondering what the best way to convert these would be and still have them work for someone with limited VBA knowledge.

Comment: That is the best I was able to do copying the macro to txt

Comment: Appears the posted macros are not Data Macros. I don't think there is any way to convert data macros to VBA.